# Displaying JSON results in a on new lines AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

Hi im retrieving some data from a database using JSON and ajax. When i grab the information i need i would like it to be displayed on a new line in the div im putting it in.

At the minute the postcodes just overwrite eachother.

```
$.ajax({    
              url: 'process.php',
              type: 'GET',
              data: 'address='+ criterion,
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data) 
              {
                  jQuery.each(data, function()
                  {
                    $('#carParkResults').html("Postcode " + data[count].postcode);
                    codeAddress(data[count].postcode);
                    alert(count);
                    count++;
                  });
              },
              error: function(e) 
              {
                //called when there is an error
                console.log(e.message);
                alert("error");
              }
    });
```

Comment: You can create a new `div` for each postcode and append that. You can also simplify your `each` loop, have a look at the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use append / appendTo to add elements to a DOM element, without overwriting the existing children of the element.

```
 $('<p>').text("Postcode " + data[count].postcode).appendTo('#carParkResults');
```

Comment: Cheers mate, i knew it would be something simple like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use .append(), .html() is always going to replace all the html inside the div.